# How do I catch errors in a JavaScript programmatically injected from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am using the content script of a Chrome extension to programmatically inject another content script that can access the web page variables and DOM. I do this on YouTube to wait for the `onYouTubePlayerReady` event.

So, I have the file `content_script.js`, which contains:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('src/js/content_script_inject.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};
```

And the file `content_script_inject.js`, which performs the actions on the webpage itself. In my injected content script, I am waiting for the `onYouTubePlayerReady` event

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  foo(); // <-- function not defined, error does not show in console
}
foo(); // <-- error shows in console
```

If a runtime error is caused by, e.g., calling a function that does not exist such as `foo()` in the above case, I do not see this error on the console when it is called from inside that function.

So: How can I catch errors generated in this JavaScript while programming it? I am assuming it is because the function is called from YouTube JavaScript instead…?

Comment: _"However, if that injected script contains a syntax error, or if any runtime error is caused by, e.g., calling a function that does not exist, I do not see this error on the console"_ That is certainly not normal. Detecting errors from code is a separate topic, but errors should be logged.

Comment: @Xan I just checked that again and you're right. Something else must've caused the sytnax error to not show up. Now indeed only runtime errors are not logged.

Comment: Are you sure there actually is an error? Can you provide (and test) a minimal example of what should fail, but doesn't print an error?

Comment: Good suggestion. The reason I didn't see any errors was because everything I did was started from inside this external function call (see updated question). When something happens outside, it is logged. But then the question is: how do I catch errors from inside the `onYouTubePlayerReady` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error is called a **runtime** error, if, well, it happens **when the code is run**.

Your script only *declares* `onYouTubePlayerReady` but does not actually run it (it's supposed to be run by something else later). As such, you can't see runtime errors: there *aren't any. Yet.*

Syntax errors, in contrast, are parse-time errors. As such, you'll see them regardless.

---

Note that in your particular case, the fact that you don't see errors probably means YouTube API either already tried to invoke the function, or never actually tries. You may want to set `run_at` content script parameter to "document_start" to exclude the first possibility.

If you are sure that the code gets executed, **it's potentially possible that the page (or YT API) has a global exception handler** that silences runtime errors. In this case, you can try to include `try...catch` in your code to catch and log exceptions before they bubble up.

Comment: Well, but *something else*, when it runs that function later, including the call to an undefined function, is still executed on my machine, no? So somewhere that call must fail. Is there no way to see when that happens?

Comment: Yes, the code is getting executed, otherwise my script wouldn't work. I am doing other things in that function. It's quite likely that YT may be silencing these errors. I'll try something and will get back to you.

Comment: Try wrapping your code in try-catch. That'll catch an exception before it's passed to calling code.

Comment: That seems to do the job, thanks. I wasn't really aware of the fact that this third-party code could basically prevent all errors from showing up.

Comment: I find it surprising, but then again, _you're invading someone else's code_ with page-level scripts. You shouldn't be surprised.